# Testing error for promise called during creation of component in vuejs using composition api

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs3, pinia, vitest

Wondering if there's a better approach to this issue. I have a component that calls a pinia store method which in turn calls an API service.

I would like the method to be called during create, so that the result can be available to the component on mount.

The method on the store is "getForecasts" and it fails on the "then" portion of the promise called inside of it. Error message is: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

If I put the method call inside another method triggered after the component is mounted, it works fine.

Perhaps this is a situation that can be accounted for in `test-utils` in some way?

Here's a simplified version of component

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useSalesStore } from '@/stores/modules'

const store = useSalesStore()

store.getForecasts({}) // test fails with error on promise call

const openSelect = () => {
  selectDialog.value = true
  store.getForecasts({}) // test is successful
}
</script>
  
<template>
  <v-btn
    data-testid="selectBtn" 
    @click="openSelect">Select</v-btn>
</template>
```